# Try to open link in new project Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

What I do wrong when I try to make an app with `PhoneGap Build`?

I want to make an app which open external link

1. I make in `CMD phonegap` project

   `phonegap create my-app`
2. Here my *config.xml* and GAP plugin

   ```
   <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
   ```
3. *index.html* BODY

   ```
   <div class="app">
       <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
       <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
           <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
           <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   app.initialize();
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {

   window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

   }
   </script>
   ```

   4. Then I make a ZIP and load to PhoneGap Build
   5. And make an APK...

But my APP doesn't open link.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a onDeviceReady function in your app object in your index.js. Try adding window.open there like this:

```js
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

},
```

Maybe you didn't install the plugin by running this command in the cmd:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

**EDIT:**

When your device is plugged in you can go to the link below and look at the console for errors:
**chrome://inspect**